# how can i access value outside the if condition in c#

Tags: c#, sql, entity

How can I use this 'download' outside the if condition?

```
if (rblFinancialYear.Checked)
{
  var download = (from appraisals in dbClientContext.PmsAppraisalActivityMasters 
                    select new
                    {
                      appraisalActivityMasteId = appraisals.AppraisalActivityMasterID,
                      empId = appraisals.EmpID,
                    })
                    Where(r => r.kpiStartDate >= dtFYStart && r.kpiStartDate <= dtFYEnd).ToList();
}
```

If I return using return type means which datatypes I use here.

Comment: What does this have to do with Javascript or jQuery? Please tag appropriately

Comment: you declare it outside of the if statement?

Comment: you dont.. scope dictates its not available.

Comment: You can't use it outside your if condition because it's declared inside your if condition. If you want to use it ouside you have to declare it outside the if condition.

Answer (score 1):

Then create the variable outside `if` condition with exact type like

```
type download = null;  
if (rblFinancialYear.Checked)
{
  //rest code
}
```

Well looks like you are projecting a `Anomymous` type as seen below and thus you have no other way than using `var` and using `var` to create variable is illegal.

```
                select new
                {
                  appraisalActivityMasteId = appraisals.AppraisalActivityMasterID,
                  empId = appraisals.EmpID,
                })
```

This the solution would to create a DTO or ViewModel and use that instead like

```
public class TestViewModel
{
  public int appraisalActivityMasteId {get; set; }
  public int empId {get; set; }
}
```

//Create variable

```
List<TestViewModel> model = null;
```

Now you can use it like

```
model = (from appraisals in dbClientContext.PmsAppraisalActivityMasters 
                    select new TestViewModel
                    {
                      appraisalActivityMasteId = appraisals.AppraisalActivityMasterID,
                      empId = appraisals.EmpID,
                    })
                    Where(r => r.kpiStartDate >= dtFYStart && r.kpiStartDate <= dtFYEnd).ToList();
}
```

Comment: It's anonymouse type if you look closer at the code

Comment: @teovankot, Yep ... observed that and thus the edited version

Answer (score 0):

You should create separate class like this:

```
public class MyDTO
{
   public int appraisalActivityMasteId {get; set;}
   public int empId {get; set;}
}
```

Maby you should use different property types. And then use it in code like this:

```
List<MyDTO> download  = new List<MyDTO>();
if (rblFinancialYear.Checked)
{
   download = (from appraisals in dbClientContext.PmsAppraisalActivityMasters 
                    select new MyDTO //note this
                    {
                      appraisalActivityMasteId = appraisals.AppraisalActivityMasterID,
                      empId = appraisals.EmpID,
                    })
                    .Where(r => r.kpiStartDate >= dtFYStart 
                       && r.kpiStartDate <= dtFYEnd).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the **download** variable a **object** type and then casting it to the type your working with when you're planning on using it.

```
object download;
if(TRUE)
{

    download = (from appraisals in dbClientContext.PmsAppraisalActivityMasters 
                        select new
                        {
                          appraisalActivityMasteId = appraisals.AppraisalActivityMasterID,
                          empId = appraisals.EmpID,
                        })
                        Where(r => r.kpiStartDate >= dtFYStart && r.kpiStartDate <= dtFYEnd).ToList();

}
```

Might work.

As for your current implementation, shown in the above code snippet example. There's no way of accessing the **download** variable outside of the **IF Statement**. It's out of scope.